# C# Debug build ok, but Release build fail due to optimized

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, release

It seems due to compiler optimization:(.net 4.0, VS2015),
This is a background worker for touch panel.

```
DispatchService.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    _vm = new TouchViewModel(Container.GetExportedValue<ITouchView>());
    _vm.ShowDialog();
});

// the background worker waiting for the Dialog show up
while (_vm == null) ; // Trace.WriteLine($"Wait _vm");
// Get Packet from Touch Panel
_vm.Points.Add(packet);
// (draw on the dialog via data binding)
```

it works at "Debug" build, but forever loop at "Release" build.
If add Trace.WriteLine in the while loop, it works too.
What is the right approach to solve it?

### No await/async because WinXP compatible(.NET 4.0)

Comment: What are you trying to do? `while (_vm == null) ;` is a recipe for disaster

Comment: That code looks a little nasty, you're dispatching the call to instantiate an object and waiting in a tight loop for it to return. It's probably the timing of the debug code that allows this to work.

Comment: Why not to use `while (true) { }`?

Comment: `_vm` in the `while (_vm == null)` loop is probably becoming enregistered. There are a range of hacks for avoiding the issue - from `volatile`, `lock`, `Thread.VolatileRead`, etc - but frankly, this is an ugly thing to be doing in the first place...

Comment: Try `while (Volatile.Read(ref _vm) == null) ;` but this whole busy-loop is really not good. Better would be to use a `ManualResetEvent`, set it when `_vm` has been allocated, and wait on the event instead of the `while` loop.

Comment: The problem is the code, not the optimizations. BTW you wouldn't even need this code if you used `async/await` or `IProgress<T>`

Comment: Besides, it's WPF. You *shouldn't* care whether the ViewModel is updated or not. Data Binding and the `PropertyChanged` interface take care of updating the UI even when you modify the viewmodel from another thread

Comment: BTW why `while (_vm == null) ; `? What code is going to execute after that? Why not put the code before and *after* the UI update into separate methods and call them with `await Task.Run(Method1); _vm=new .....; awati Task.Run(Method2);` ?

Comment: Or better yet, perform any post-processing in an event handler that is fired when the dialogue is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to block execution until delegate will be executed in some other thread then implementing a proper synchronization is a key.

To example, you can use [`Monitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// field somewhere
readonly object _lock = new object();

// then
DispatchService.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    _vm = new TouchViewModel(Container.GetExportedValue<ITouchView>());
    lock(_lock)
        Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
    _vm.ShowDialog();
});
lock(_lock)
    Monitor.Wait(_lock);
```

Comment: I thought you want to wait for dialog to close, but in your edit of question it seems you want to simply execute some code while dialog is displayed (are you waiting for dialog to appears or just for `_vm` initialization?). If so, then probably a better solution is to subscribe to event, e.g. `Loaded` and run the code there.

Comment: Hi, Sinatr, you got my purpose. I use MVVM, those source code are in the Application assembly, not the Presentation assembly, so it should be fine. Thanks your comment!

Comment: Finally I use ManualResetEventSlim